# how to cluster values of continuous time series

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

[image]

In the picture I plot the values from an array of shape (400,8)
I wish to reorganize the points in order to get 8 series of "continuous" points. Let's call them a(t), b(t), .., h(t). a(t) being the serie with the smaller values and h(t) the serie with the bigger value. They are unknown and I try to obtain them

I have some missing values replaced by 0.

When there is a 0, I do not know to which serie it belongs to. The zeros are always stored with high index in the array
For instance at time t=136 I have only 4 values that are valid. Then array[t,i] > 0 for i <=3 and array[t,i] = 0 for i > 3

How can I cluster the points in a way that I get "continuous" time series i.e. at time t=136, array[136,0] should go into d, array[136,1] should go into e, array[136,2] should go into f and array[136,3] should go into g

I tried AgglomerativeClustering and DBSCAN with scikit-learn with no success.

Data are available at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DKgx95FAqAIlabq77F9f-5vO-WPj7Puw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your array's shape is (400,8) and you know exactly where the zeroes are.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that you mean that you have the data in 400 columns and 8 rows. The data values are assigned to the correct columns, but not necessarily to the correct rows. Your figure shows that the 8 signals do not cross each other, so you should be able to simply sort each column individually.  But now the missing data is the problem, because the zeros representing missing data will all sort to the bottom rows, forcing the real data into the wrong rows.

I don't know if this is a good answer, but my first hunch is to start by sorting each column individually, then beginning in a place where there are several adjacent columns with full spans of real data, and working away from that location first to the left and then to the right, one column at a time: If the column contains no zeros, it is OK. If it contains zeros, then compute **local row averages** of the immediately adjacent columns, using only non-zero values (the number of columns depends on the density of missing data and the resolution between the signals), and then put each valid value in the current column into the row with the closest 'local row average' value, and put zeros in the remaining rows.  How to code that depends on what you have done so far.  If you are using numpy, then it would be convenient to first convert the zeros to NaN's, because numpy.nanmean() will ignore the NaN's.